# about call Chrome API or Chrome Extensions with Javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, text-to-speech

I write a HTML page and I want call a Chrome API(eg tts) with a Javascript function which in my HTML page.

BTW: I don't want to create a Chrome Extensions, just want run as a web app.

Is that possible ? If can be possible, how do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

With very few exceptions, `chrome.*` APIs can only be used within the context of a chrome extension.  There are a few exceptions, but probably none that you want.  To see them, press F12, type `chrome` into the prompt, and click to expand the returned opject.